# How to add an application settings in android system settings?

Tags: android, android-settings

In my application i have a requirement that i want to provide one edit text in the system settings menu to enter URL  and my application hit the server based on the user given URL in system setting. Is it possible ? If it is possible please can any one help me to do this.

It is possible in IPhone as they are having a setting.Bundle.
Do we have any framework in android similar to IOS?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: what u mean by system settings menu

Comment: Default android settings.

Comment: no you cant do anything with android settings

Comment: You can't mess with **system** settings. Only with **application** settings.

Comment: You can add your application to [Account sync](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html). Then your application will show up under Accounts in the android device. You can have an `EditText` there. You can't add your application anywhere else in the Settings.

Comment: Can you please provide any reference for this.

Comment: @SumanCh [This](http://www.finalconcept.com.au/article/view/android-account-manager-step-by-step-2) is the first search result I got.

Comment: @SumanCh [This](http://udinic.wordpress.com/2013/04/24/write-your-own-android-authenticator/) is the second.

Answer (score 3):

You can add the intent-filter blew at your activity in manifest.xml, add it will make a link at system setting -> appinfo -> your app detail | addtional settings. and click it will jump to yout activity.

this is very deep path, but it work.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.APPLICATION_PREFERENCES" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

Another way:
check and read a file like "debug.properties" from sdcard, then read the url properties.