# How to add own setting into android system settings?

Tags: android, android-settings

Hi I'm creating a simple app for change background but I want to put into system settings and hide from menu apps like [Kidlogger Pro](https://kidlogger.net/kidlogger-android-pro.html). I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26966179/how-to-add-an-application-settings-in-android-system-settings) but it is only available with TTS options?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want to put into system settings

Settings is its own app; you cannot modify that app.

> I found this answer but it is only available with TTS options?

The Settings app offers a couple of places where it will link to some activity of yours, to offer user configuration of certain features. In general, those are tied to very specific things (e.g., configuring an input method editor) and are *not* general-purpose solutions.

Android 7.0+ allows you to [designate an activity that is linked to from your app's  screen in Settings](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/08/17/application_preferences-security.html) (Apps > (your app name)). This is the closest thing that Android has to what you are seeking.

You cannot invent new categories (e.g., "Apps", "Display", "Security"), and you cannot invent new settings in existing categories. For those things, the user should launch your main activity, and either configure that stuff there, or open up some dedicated settings screen from there.

Comment: Wow, thanks, You know which another places can I link some activity? like input method?

Comment: @CamiRodriguez: I do not have a list off the top of my head.

Comment: @CamiRodriguez: Sorry, but I do not know what you mean.

Answer (score -1):

By default, **you can't**. You can **root** your phone in order to change settings application.